# Перегрузка оператора присваивания

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

В программе есть класс `Player`, `Animation`.

```
class Player
{
 ...
 Animation* currentAnimation;
 Animation anim1;
 Animation anim2;
 void Update(bool state);
 ...
 //при создании экземпляра класса currentAnimation инициализируется
}
void Player::Update(bool state)
{
   if(state) currentAnimation = &anim1;
   if(!state) currentAnimation = &anim2;
}
```

Мне нужно при присваивании обнулять одно из полей. То есть при таком присваивании: `currentAnimation = &anim1;` у `anim1` должно обнуляться, допустим, поле `pole1`.
Я перегружал оператор присваивания в классе `Animation` таким образом:

```
Animation & Animation::operator=(Animation & anim)
{
    if (this != &anim)
    {
        //тут присваиваются остальные поля
        //по типу this->pole2 = anim.pole2;
        ...
        anim.pole1 = 0;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Все работает, но поле не обнуляется.

Comment: Оператор присваивания должен работать. Но строка ** if(state) currentAnimation = anim1;** странная. Здесь указателю присваивается объект. Это не должно компилироваться по умолчанию.

Comment: Да, ошибся. Там currentAnimation = &anim1;

Comment: А зачем вам это понадобилось? Почему вдруг присваивание `currentAnimation = anim1` будет модифицировать свою правую часть?

Comment: @AnT ностальгия по `auto_ptr` может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш оператор вызывается при присваивании объектов, но не их адресов. Т.е. он бы вызывался, если бы было

```
currentAnimation = anim1;
```

где и `currentAnimation`, и `anim1` были объектами. Но у вас присваивание адреса переменной указателю, и в этом случае нет никакого вызова оператора присваивания, а простая запись 32 (ну, или 64 - в зависимости от разрядности) бит адреса в некоторое место в памяти...

Предупреждая вопрос - "а как..." - а никак. Руками обнуляйте. Не работают тут никакие операторы - ну судите сами, пусть вы правы и нужно вызывать оператор при присваивании указателей... что делать в таком случае:

```
Animation *a1, *a2, anim;
a2 = a1;
a1 = &anim;
a2 = a1;
```

Следует ли в третьем присваивании вызывать тот же оператор? А в первом, когда указатель указывает не пойми куда? А при `a1=nullptr`?

Думаю, вы поняли, почему это (вызов оператора) при присваивании указателей не делается?

P.S. И, кстати, "все работает" - да ничего не работает. Просто после присваивания указателей у вас `currentAnimation->pole` просто эквивалентно `anim1->pole` потому, что они указывают на одно место, а не потому, что вы что-то там скопировали...